# string substitution in many files

Tags: perl, replace

I am using the command

```
perl -pe 's/ReplaceThis/`cat T1.php`/ge' -i T1.php.txt
```

to substitute the string "ReplaceThis" in the file T1.php.txt with the content of the file T1.php, and it works fine. But I would like to do this for hundreds of files at once, Ti.php for 1<=i<=700. I am trying

```
for file in *.php; do perl -pe 's/ReplaceThis/`cat "$file"`/ge' -i 
"$file".txt ; done
```

but I get the error:
cat: : No such file or directory
How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to generate Perl code from a shell script! Use some other means (args, env, fd, file) to pass the information to the script.

One solution:

```
for file in *.php; do
    perl -i -pe'
       BEGIN { local $/; $repl = <STDIN>; }
       s/ReplaceThis/$repl/g;
    ' "$file".txt <"$file"
done
```